# Can I access a azure-storage-file from my app-service via unc-path?

Tags: azure, unc, azure-app-service-envrmnt, azure-storage-files

I have an azure-app-service where I want to access files on the azure-storage. If I use the CloudStorageAccount it works well.

But the problem is, that I have a native library loaded, which uses UNC-Paths to access its files. I found a way set login-credentials on my local system. But cannot connect cause of the blocked port 445.

The port-problem shouldn't be on the cloud. But it seems I can't set credentials there anymore. It always tells me I probably don't have rights to access the network resources("ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED"). I'm using the function "WNetAddConnection2A"(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnetwk/nf-winnetwk-wnetaddconnection2a).

If I just try to use the UNC-Path I get the exception "UnauthorizedAccessException".

Is it even possible to access storage-files from my app-service via UNC-Path?

Answer (score 1):

You can not use Azure Files and access UNC paths from code running in an App Service, this is due to the sandbox that App Service uses